# what code of 'digit' range for a char is fastest?

Tags: c

I thought of simple function in C which take a *char* and return a *bool* for any character that represent a digit.

I have two codes. The first

```c
bool isDigit(char c){

    uint8_t num = c - '0';
    if(num >= 0 && num <= 9) return true;
    return false;
}
```

And the second:

```c
bool isDigit(char c){

    switch(c - '0'){
   
        case 0: return true;
        case 1: return true;
        case 2: return true;
        case 3: return true;
        case 4: return true;
        case 5: return true;
        case 6: return true;
        case 7: return true;
        case 8: return true;
        case 9: return true;

        default: return false;
    }
}
```

I read that *switch* is faster that *if*, but thinking about it; in the second code, it would do a comparison for each *case* until match, but in the first, it would do just two comparison.

Comment: I'd stick with the standard `isdigit()` and not worry about micro optimizations unless profiling suggests it's an actual issue.

Comment: (but I'd use a `UCHAR_MAX + 1` sized Boolean array or `switch` with the actual character instead of doing math; the compiler's optimizer can probably turn the `switch` into an array lookup if it thinks it'll be more efficient on whatever hardware it's targeting)

Comment: The first version can be simplified to `return c >= '0' && c <= '9';`

Comment: And the second also: `case '0' :` etc.

Comment: Is this really worth worrying about?  If you cannot answer your own question by measuring the performance of your application with each implementation, then this is not worth worrying about, the effort would be better spent in other areas.  I would be amazed if either made a significant difference in all but the most unrealistic benchmark.  Unless this is pretty much all your code does all the time.

Comment: both functions compile to identical branchless code on gcc and clang with `-O3`: https://godbolt.org/z/4Gsh6nc7n

Comment: Style note: `if(num >= 0 && num <= 9) return true; return false;` == `return num >= 0 && num <= 9;`

Comment: @bolov thanks for the page. It's really cool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What method of determining whether a character is a digit **is** the fastest depends on the target platform, including the implementation of the C library, the compiler (notably its optimizer), characteristics of the target processor, and possibly properties of the specific program and situation, including cache use, register use, and more.

The method of using `isdigit((unsigned char) c)` **should be** fast, because that is largely what it is designed for, and the implementors of it and the compiler should work to make it fast.

It may not be fastest for several reasons, including:

- `isdigit` must also handle an input of `EOF`. A function that can assume its input is a character value, not `EOF`, might have an edge, although likely not much and possibly not at all.
- `isdigit` is commonly implemented using a table shared by other routines declared in `<ctype.h>`. An implementation dedicated solely to `isdigit` might use a smaller table (and hence less cache) or other optimizations.
- Specific circumstances may enable some custom implementation to be faster.

Between the two in the post, the `switch` test is likely not to be faster than the `if` test, as any implementation of it likely involves comparing values anyway.

The first implementation might as well be `return '0' <= num && num <= '9';`, as there is no benefit to subtracting `'0'` first or to using an `if` rather than directly returning the result of the expression.

Comment: Thanks man. It makes sense what you say. Im trying to do a csv reader and I have a union that store the cell value. I'm assume that isidigt never take EOF file because the loop breaks before that happends.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for DIY portable function then lookup table one will be probably the fastest.

```
bool tt[256] = {['0'] = true, ['1'] = true, ['2'] = true, ['3'] = true, ['4'] = true, 
                ['5'] = true, ['6'] = true, ['7'] = true, ['8'] = true, ['9'] = true, };


bool myisdigit(unsigned char c)
{
    return tt[c];
}
```

x86:

```
myisdigit:
        movzx   edi, dil
        movzx   eax, BYTE PTR tt[rdi]
        ret
tt:
        .zero   48
        .byte   1
        .byte   1
        .byte   1
        .byte   1
        .byte   1
        .byte   1
        .byte   1
        .byte   1
        .byte   1
        .byte   1
        .zero   198
```

ARM Cortex-M0:

```
myisdigit:
        ldr     r3, .L3
        ldrb    r0, [r3, r0]
        bx      lr
.L3:
        .word   tt
tt:
        .space  48
        .byte   1
        .byte   1
        .byte   1
        .byte   1
        .byte   1
        .byte   1
        .byte   1
        .byte   1
        .byte   1
        .byte   1
        .space  198
```

AVR:

```
        mov r30,r24
        ldi r31,0
        subi r30,lo8(-(tt))
        sbci r31,hi8(-(tt))
        ld r24,Z
        ret
tt:
        .zero   48
        .byte   1
        .byte   1
        .byte   1
        .byte   1
        .byte   1
        .byte   1
        .byte   1
        .byte   1
        .byte   1
        .byte   1
        .zero   198
```

It will be fast when you work with strings. If you want to handle EOF, write a wrapper checking for EOF first. It

Comment: On AVR `bool isDigit (char c) { return c >= '0' && c <= '9'; }` also just needs 6 cycles but no RAM and with less register pressure. On x86_64 it takes 3 instructions, but I don't know if that beats the memory access.